# Website background turns dim when focus on form input

Tags: css, background

I have a website that has a big search form and a big website background. I had an idea for my website. That is to make the website background dim when i click on the search form. But then, I saw same thing at bing.com. I tried to do it using css but failed no matter what i try. Any idea to make it happen?

**Update**

I have this now in my css file.

```
#dim {width:100%; opacity:0; background:#000; position:absolute; height:100%;}
```

I want a JS code to make it the `opacity` turns to `0.5` when i click on my form.

Below is the code of my form.

```
<form name="searchform" onsubmit="return !!(validateSearch() &amp;&amp; dosearch());">
<input type="text" name="searchterms" class="terms" id="terms" placeholder="What are you searching for?">
<select name="sengines" class="state" id="state">
<option value="" selected>Select a State</option>
<option value="http://kl.onehomereno.com?s=">Klang Valley</option>
</select>

<div class="pad10"></div>
<input name="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="button3">
</form>
```

I have the `terms` as id. Therefore, i need a js code to work with `#terms` and `#dim`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: Have you tried looking at how it's done on Bing? Are you sure it's just CSS, rather than involving JS?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i am not sure. Do you have any clue to make this happen?

Comment: Use some JS to toggle a class on whatever elements you want to change when the input gains or loses focus, would be the most straightforward. I don't know if you can do this only with CSS.

Comment: Do you have any js script? I'm not good in coding js script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **JavaScript** to listen for `clicks` on the form element and change `opacity` of the `class` with the `background`

For example

EDIT:

**CSS**

```
.dim {
background: url("home_page.PNG") no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
opacity: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dim"></div>
<input type="text" id="term">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#term').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.dim').css('opacity', '0.5');
    });
    $(document).on("click", function() {
        $(this).find('.dim').css('opacity', '0');
    });
});
```

Hope you get how this works.

Comment: Oke Tega, i tried your code, but i don't find how it works.

Comment: Then maybe i dont understand what you want

Comment: I have already updated my question. When i put the `opacity` to `0.5`, this code is work. So, i set it to `0` as default. What i want is, when the time i click my form, the dim will work as `o.5` in opacity.

Comment: Can't find any `element` in you `html` with `#dim`

Comment: Plus i ask, what do you really want? Is that when user clicks on an `id` something changes opacity?

Comment: No. The `#dim` is not inside the code of form. It's outside of form code but inside the HTML of the webpage.

Comment: is it that when they click on `#term`, `#dim` changes `opacity` to `0.5`

Comment: Yes. When people click the form, hope to get `js code` to change the opacity. You are right.

Comment: Yes. You got what I mean.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please tick as the right answer if it worked for you

Comment: Sure. I haven't tried yet as I'm outside now. I will do so if the code works. 

Comment: I tried. But it is still not working. I'm not sure if there is something missing?
`<script>
$('#terms').on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).focus()) {
            $('.dim').css('opacity', '0.5');
        } else {
            $('.dim').css('opacity', '0');
        }
    });
</script>` This is the code i put on my html file.

Comment: A good news. It works. But, it has to be work with jquery link. `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`. But, there was an issue. That is, when the time i focus, it was dim. But, the dim is still remain when i'm not focus on the `#terms`. What else i can do?

Comment: Thanks Tega! This code works well now. Appreciate your help!